# CSS + jQuery Transform plugin: how to fix blurry text

Tags: jquery, css, transform, antialiasing

So I've got an odd situation.

I've had to scale up a whole bunch of content using the scale plugin, which I suppose uses css 3 transforms.

When I click on a button that animates a layer beneath the text, I get a "flash" of crisp anti-aliased text (Actually, I hide/reveal text at this time, too).  Then about 500 ms later, all the text goes back to being blurry. I can repeat this over and over. The REALLY  WEIRD PART is that it goes back to being blurry before the under-layer finishes animating. Now, I would expect that if this is a "delay in adding the transform" then the new text would not be the "correct" size at first, but it is correct at the beginning.

[image: On the left when at rest, on the right first 500 ms]

```
    /* I've added this, too:*/
        -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;

    /* also tried */
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    // the basic implementation of the transform using jQuery 2D transform plugin
    $("#container").transform({
        origin: ['50%', '0px'], 
        scaleX: _scaleY,
        scaleY: _scaleY
    });

   // tried this too, but doesn't seem to do anything at all
   $('#container').animate({
       transform: 'scale(' + _scaleY + ')',
       time:.5
   });
```

*EDIT* Seems like chrome only.

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers

Comment: Good point. Just tried in FF and IE9, and it looks okay. The above result is in  Chrome.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that Chrome has its own font smoothing engine. Don't quote me on that.

Comment: Scale plugin / CSS3 implementations still need some work. I've noticed that where image src swapping happens or new images are added to the DOM, elements "snap" into place in firefox. Plus the blurry thing. jQuery.effects.scale is not much better. yay, breaks flash too in FF.

Comment: SO I have to ignore Firefox because it don't support zoom properly, but I found that I can use the browser "zoom" (CSS3 zoom) very carefully to rescale the page as desired fine in chrome/ie. Granted probably should have been a more liquid layout, it was designed to a specific dimension spec-- that later had to be fluid.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in Chrome/Safari on a css transform of a background layer and adding the font smoothing property worked in Chrome 37.

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```